# XPath syntax with multiple conditions

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I'm new to Selenium and I'm not very familiar with coding, so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to check item on website and have added first item to go to basket and proceed to checkout.

Everything works, but I need to add condition criteria, where sellers name or price is also checked, so let's say - if item is sold by Cody **OR** price is 200EUR - only then add to cart. (one condition or two of them match, then "add to cart" in other cases `print("Item not available")`

[See attached picture of the store for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cuX3.jpg)

My code is:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
while (True):
try:
    wd.get ("http://majasadrese.lv/test_adrese")
    a_autoid_2_offer_1 = wd.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="a-autoid-2-offer-1"]')
    a_autoid_2_offer_1.click()
    break
except NoSuchElementException:
    print(“Item not available”)
time.sleep(10)
```

Where

```
a_autoid_2_offer_1 = wd.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="a-autoid-2-offer-1"]')
        a_autoid_2_offer_1.click()
```

is first "Add to cart" on top of the page in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

**Condition within a singe node**

If we talk about a single node, it's simply

```
//*[(condition1) or (condition2)]
```

e.g.

```
//*[(@id="a-autoid-2-offer-1") or (text()="200EUR")]
```

**Condition for multiple nodes**

But if you like to check some conditions for multiple nodes, you have to

1. Find the first node (node1) by condition1
2. Go down/up or following/previous to another node(node2) by condition2
3. Return back to the node1

Simple example

for this html

```
<div class="some-div-class active">
    <a href="some-href-1">a1-text</a>
</div>
<div class="some-div-class">
    <a href="some-href-1">a2-text</a>
</div>
...
```

this

```
//div[(contains(@class, 'some-div-class')) and (contains(@class, 'active'))]//a[starts-with(@href, 'some-href')]/..
```

will find the `div` with

- condition1: both classes `some-div-clas`, `active`

and

- condition2: with a child `a` with `href` started with `some-href`

```
1. condition1 - node1
//div[(contains(@class, 'some-div-class')) and (contains(@class, 'active'))]

2. condition2 - node2
//a[starts-with(@href, 'some-href')]

3. return back to node1
/..
```